# How will BSS138 work if I apply the same voltage to both the LV (low voltage) and the HV (high voltage)?

Tags: mosfet

I'm making a circuit to connect to a UART pins on a mini PC. But it is possible to use different mini PCs, one using 3.3V TX and RX levels and the other 5V.

I have BSS138 and I'm wondering if I could use a jumper to switch the LV (low voltage) between 3.3 V and 5 V? My circuit is equipped with both 3.3V and 5V.

In one case, LV = 3.3 V and HV = 5 V.

In the other, LV = HV = 5 V.

Will I be able to use 2x BSS138 for input and output, if their LV and HV pins are connected to 5 volts?

Ok, sorry! I thought the question was clear. I added a diagram, which I quickly drew. So when W1 is clear and W2 set, LV = HV = 5V, in the other case W1 is set and W2 clear, LV = 3.3V, HV = 5V.
Either jumper W1 or jumper W2 will be installed, not both.

[image]

Comment: You must be thinking of a certain level conversion circuit with resistors of some values, but unfortunately we can't be sure what you mean. Please edit in a schematic with labels explaining what exactly you mean to connect and how.

Comment: You may want to review how the PC and MCU will communicate using UART protocol. Usually, two equipment communicating through UART connections have their RX (TX) pin connected to the other equipment TX (RX) pin. You have shown the RX (TX) pin of the PC connected to the RX (TX) pin of the MCU. they should be criss-crossed.

Comment: @VictorTito: Actually while the scheme you describe is common, it doesn't apply to UARTs, which are specified so that RX connects to RX and TX to TX.  Which of RX or TX is the input and which is the output depends on whether the equipment is DTE or DCE.  Now, if instead of making a connection between DTE and DCE, you want to connect two DTE together, then yes you need the cross-connection, called a "null modem".

Comment: @BenVoigt, Thanks for refreshing my memory.

Comment: @BenVoigt, reviewing some of my very old books, I found Douglas V HAll book showing when connecting DTE (PC) to DCE (modem) and vice-versa (figure 13-2) and DTE to DTE (figure 13-10) using the null-modem cable. Unless the MCU is acting as a modem I still believe you need to cross-connect.

Comment: @Ted, I am just mentioning the above because I found in the NET several situations of PC to MCU connections where connecting RX (TX) to RX (TX) did not work. Better check if your MCU and PC will be working as a DTE or DCE.

Comment: @VictorTito , Thank you very much for your support and attention. In fact, I plan to connect TX with RX and RX with TX, but for me it is important that on the board on which the microcontroller is, its TX and RX are marked. See the arrow from the PC connector. It is the direction of RX ( PC TX ) to RX ( MCU ). This will make it easier for me to connect MCU board with the PC. These types of connections are always confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit that you've shown will work perfectly fine.